# Could someone help explain what this C one liner does?

Tags: c

I can usually figure out most C code but this one is over my head.

```
#define kroundup32(x) (--(x), (x)|=(x)>>1, (x)|=(x)>>2, (x)|=(x)>>4, (x)|=(x)>>8, (x)|=(x)>>16, ++(x))
```

an example usage would be something like:

```
int x = 57;
kroundup32(x);
//x is now 64
```

A few other examples are:

1 to 1
2 to 2
7 to 8
31 to 32
60 to 64
3000 to 4096

I know it's rounding an integer to it's nearest power of 2, but that's about as far as my knowledge goes.

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(--(x), (x)|=(x)>>1, (x)|=(x)>>2, (x)|=(x)>>4, (x)|=(x)>>8, (x)|=(x)>>16, ++(x))
```

1. Decrease x by 1
2. OR x with (x / 2).
3. OR x with (x / 4).
4. OR x with (x / 16).
5. OR x with (x / 256).
6. OR x with (x / 65536).
7. Increase x by 1.

For a 32-bit unsigned integer, this should move a value up to the closest power of 2 that is equal or greater.  The OR sections set all the lower bits below the highest bit, so it ends up as a power of 2 minus one, then you add one back to it.  It looks like it's somewhat optimized and therefore not very readable; doing it by bitwise operations and bit shifting alone, and as a macro (so no function call overhead).

Comment: Great, I understand what it's doing now.  Thank you!

Comment: +1 for one who encoded(optimized) it & +1 for @thomasrutter for decoding it :)

Comment: No, it shifts the highest bit by 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31 bits.

Comment: Here's an alternative explanation: It works by copying the highest set bit to all of the lower bits, and then adding one, which results in carries that set all of the lower bits to 0 and one bit beyond the highest set bit to 1. If the original number was a power of 2, then the decrement will reduce it to one less, so that we round up to the same original value. [Source](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2)

Answer (score 6):

The bitwise or and shift operations essentially set every bit between the highest set bit and bit zero.  This will produce a number of the form `2^n - 1`.  The final increment adds one to get a number of the form `2^n`.  The initial decrement ensures that you don't round numbers which are already powers of two up to the next power, so that e.g. 2048 doesn't become 4096.

Answer (score 6):

At my machine `kroundup32` gives 6.000m rounds/sec
And next function gives 7.693m rounds/sec

```
inline int scan_msb(int x)
{
#if defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__)
    int y;
    __asm__("bsr %1, %0"
            : "=r" (y)
            : "r" (x)
            : "flags"); /* ZF */
    return y;
#else
#error "Implement me for your platform"
#endif
}

inline int roundup32(int x)
{
    if (x == 0) return x;
    else {
        const int bit = scan_msb(x);
        const int mask = ~((~0) << bit);
        if (x & mask) return (1 << (bit+1));
        else return (1 << bit);
    }
}
```

So @thomasrutter I woudn't say that it is "highly optimized".

And appropriate (only meaningful part) assembly (for GCC 4.4.4):

```
kroundup32:
    subl    $1, %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    sarl    %eax
    orl %edi, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $2, %edx
    orl %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sarl    $4, %eax
    orl %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $8, %edx
    orl %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sarl    $16, %eax
    orl %edx, %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    ret

roundup32:
    testl   %edi, %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    je  .L6
    movl    $-1, %edx
    bsr %edi, %ecx
    sall    %cl, %edx
    notl    %edx
    testl   %edi, %edx
    jne .L10
    movl    $1, %eax
    sall    %cl, %eax
.L6:
    rep
    ret
.L10:
    addl    $1, %ecx
    movl    $1, %eax
    sall    %cl, %eax
    ret
```

By some reason I haven't found appropriate implementation of `scan_msb` (like `#define scan_msb(x) if (__builtin_constant_p (x)) ...`) within standart headers of GCC (only [`__TBB_machine_lg`/`__TBB_Log2`](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2007-September/021846.html)).

Comment: fair enough.  I guess you could say that whoever wrote it was *attempting* to make something highly optimised, even though that attempt may not have been hugely successful ;)